# Android studio(java) navigation drawer click action don't work as expect

Tags: android

index.xml

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".index_activity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="start">
        <include layout="@layout/nav_drawer"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/frame_layout"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
            app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="50dp">

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />

        </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_24"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
            app:maxImageSize="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            app:tint="@color/orangeInFigma" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="176dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_3_shape"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_24"
        android:background="@drawable/balance_shape"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="welcome, user 123"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="123@gmail.com"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

nav_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_3_shape"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_24"
        android:background="@drawable/balance_shape"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="welcome, user 123"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="123@gmail.com"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_home"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Home"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/baseline_home_24"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/action3"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Achievement"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/baseline_achievement_24"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/action4"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Settings"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/baseline_achievement_24"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@color/orangeInFigma"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Logout"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/baseline_exit_to_app_24"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

index_activity.java

```
package com.example.testagain;


import static android.app.ProgressDialog.show;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;


import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class index_activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseAuth auth;

    FirebaseUser user;
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ImageView menu;
    LinearLayout home,settings,achievement,logout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.index);

        //check login
        auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user=auth.getCurrentUser();

        //bottom navigation bar
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        //navigation drawer
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        menu = findViewById(R.id.menu);
        home= findViewById(R.id.bottom_home);
        settings = findViewById(R.id.action4);
        logout = findViewById(R.id.logout);
        achievement=findViewById(R.id.action3);

        menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    closeDrawer(drawerLayout);
                } else {
                    openDrawer(drawerLayout);
                }
            }
        });

        home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(index_activity.this, "you click home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                recreate();
            }
        });

        settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(index_activity.this, "you click settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                redirectActivity(index_activity.this,com.example.testagain.settings.class);
            }
        });

        achievement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(index_activity.this, "you click achievement", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                redirectActivity(index_activity.this,com.example.testagain.achievement.class);
            }
        });

        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(index_activity.this, "you click logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });







        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showBottomDialog();
            }
        });

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int itemId = item.getItemId();
                if(itemId == R.id.bottom_home){
                    openFragment(new HomeFragment());
                } else if(itemId == R.id.distract){
                    openFragment(new PlanningFragment());
                }else if(itemId == R.id.action3){
                    openFragment(new AchievementFragment());
                }else if(itemId == R.id.action4){
                    openFragment(new SettingsFragment());
                }
                //drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            }
        });






    }






    public static void openDrawer(DrawerLayout drawerLayout){

        drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }

    public static void closeDrawer(DrawerLayout drawerLayout){
        if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    }

    public static void redirectActivity(Activity activity,Class secondActivity){
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity,secondActivity);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
        activity.finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        closeDrawer(drawerLayout);
    }

    private  void openFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }


    private void showBottomDialog() {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.bottomsheetlayout);

        LinearLayout videoLayout = dialog.findViewById(R.id.layoutVideo);
        LinearLayout shortsLayout = dialog.findViewById(R.id.layoutShorts);
        ImageView cancelButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);

        videoLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Upload a Video is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        shortsLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Create a short is Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });



        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
        dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

    }


}
```

on my index.xml, I can click on bottom navigation and it works.
But at my navigation drawer, I can open the drawer but the option to click is not working.
I have check the java code and it works by moving the `<include layout="@layout/nav_drawer"/\>` on index.xml outside the relativelayout.
But if I do that, the drawer could not be closed and always open.
So I think is the xml position problem, but I can't found out what problem is.